# Moving files into folders

Tags: windows, file, explorer

I have thousands of image files in a folder and I want a program to automatically create new folders and put fifty files in each folder. Any Idea?

Comment: Yes, learn about using Windows powershell https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell  ... should be "piece of cake" to do something like that.

Comment: As GhostCat mentioned, you could use PowerShell. Windows batch is another option. Once you write either, you can use Windows task scheduler if you need this to run multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

something like this;

```
int i = 0;

string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\ALLFILESHERE\");

foreach (string fileName in filePaths)
{
        i++;

        bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(i));

        if(!exists)
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(i));

        for (int j = 1; j < 50; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                var to = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\i\", fileName);

                File.Move(fileName , to); // Try to move
                Console.WriteLine("Moved"); // Success
             }
             catch (IOException ex)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(ex); // Write error
             }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file having name say `movefiles.bat`, paste the below contents inside the file and place it inside the folder where you have thousands of files. Now open `cmd` and run the `bat` file or just double click the `bat file`.

```
@ECHO on
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET foldersize=30
SET counter=1
SET numFiles=0
::extension of the to be mentioned here as *.txt or *.jpg etc
FOR %%f IN (*.jpg) DO (
IF !counter!==1 (
SET /A numFiles+=1
MD folder!numFiles!
) 
MOVE /Y "%%f" folder!numFiles!
IF !counter!==!foldersize! (
SET counter=1
) ELSE (
SET /A counter+=1
)
)
ENDLOCAL
PAUSE
```

It will create the folders and put the number of files specified in the `foldersize`.

Comment: @Ela what is not working i have tried this in my folder and its working, what is the file extension you want to move? change the extension `FOR %%f IN (*.jpg) DO` in this line to your extension `*.jpg` to `*.txt`or anything else

Comment: it worked thanks. that folder contained file of various format. that was the problem